# Django Rosetta does not translate variables

Tags: python, django, translation

I know this would not add generated string to django.po file:

```
{% trans var %}
```

As well as:

```
ugettext(var)
```

I just wonder how dynamic translations should be handled. Variable values are stored in PSQL.

Comment: Translation files are not dynamic, so it is not a good idea to put dynamic values in there. It might be a good idea to store the translated values in the DB as well.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. is it possible, by any chance, to import strings from **psql** to **django.po**? Specifying exact table for it would be great. I just want to update my **django.po** file with whatever value stored in `var`